# AWS Architecture to call sharepoint

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking to create a AWS Architecture which should do a API call to a sharepoint hosted on client secured environment and move data to s3 bucket.
I have kindoff created an architecture for a same where API gateway make a API call to sharepoint thne use lambda to move data to s3.

But the ask here from client is that the API request should be made from client side and they should push the data from there. Was thinking is there any middleware script or something which can be deployed on client system which can help us and how it's AWS Architecture would look like.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want architecture or more understanding of how AWS works.

Well you can use any of AWS SDKs according to client side technologies and upload the file to S3 directly. You don't have to call any API to just move data to S3. Even if you do for whatever reason then you can host your APIs on Lambda, expose via API Gateway and call this API from client side. *Security and other aspects are outside of discussion of the question.

Comment: Thanks Hussain for the quick responce. For now i need to just build the technical architecture to depict the working.
I just need to understand the part in more detail where you said 'call this API from client side'. What needs to be done/deployed on client side so that they can crawl the sharepoint website and push the code to AWS?

Comment: This is a documentation on AWS S3 which shows various ways on how you can upload something on S3. You can use AWS CLI, SDK, APIs on your client server. Check the documentation and ask specific problem around the issue you're facing.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html